# How to render an HTML file offline?

Tags: html, html-parsing

I have a collection of html files that I gathered from a website using wget. Each file name is of the form [details.php?id=100419&cid=13%0D](http://snipt.org/embed/mpmmk), where the id and cid varies. Portions of the html files contain articles in Asian language (Unicode text). My intention is to extract the Asian-language text only. Dumping the rendered html using a command-line browser is the first step that I have thought of. It will eliminate some of the frills.

The problem is, I cannot dump the rendered html to a file (using, say, w3m -dump ). The dumping works if only I direct the browser (at the command-line) to the properly formed URL : `http://<blah-blah>/<filename>`. But this is way I will have to spend the time to download the files once again from the web. How do I get around this, what other tools could I use?

`w3m -dump <filename>` complains saying:
*w3m: Can't load details.php?id=100419&cid=13%0D.*

`file <filname>` shows:
*details.php?id=100419&cid=13%0D: Non-ISO extended-ASCII HTML document text, with very long lines, with CRLF, CR, LF, NEL line terminators*

Comment: Have you tried the URL: file://<filename> ?

Comment: Tried it, says 'can't load file ...' again.

Comment: Can copy an exact command you are trying to use here?  The `&` in the URL might be causing some problems since it is a special character in shell land.  You could try quoting (`"`) the file name to remedy that.

Comment: I don't know anything about command-line browsers or w3m dumping, but you could use a JavaScript script to parse the HTML files and extract the content. jQuery can parse HTML files retrieved via Ajax into objects, and then jQuery's selector engine can be used to locate the content.

Comment: @mjschultz : At the Linux shell prompt I used \ (backslash) before the characters like & , ? , =, %. The url works fine because w3m is then able to download and render the page.